# How can I decrease key repetition time in gnome-terminal like konsole in KDE?

Tags: keyboard, configuration, gnome-terminal, system-settings

I liked the feature or more quicker key repetition time in [Konsole](http://konsole.kde.org/) *(KDE's terminal)*. The feature is actually, If you write a long line and wanted to delete it by pressing and holding the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key, the line start deleting quickly.

But, in gnome-terminal *(Default Ubuntu's default terminal)* it required more time. You have to hold the backspace button more time than in konsole.

My question is: How can I reduce this time in gnome-terminal? or How can I make gnome-terminal to trigger key repetition quickly?

Note: I am asking it not only for deleting line, but also for going to specific position in line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To customize the delay until a key is repeated in Ubuntu, do:

1. Open Dash (Super key).
2. Search for `keyboard` and click on the `Keyboard` result.
3. A new window opens where you can set the delay and speed.

This is the picture from `System Settings --> Keyboard` windows

[image]

In the terminal, these hotkeys may be useful:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> to delete the characters from the cursor to the beginning of the line.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> to delete the characters from the cursor to the left until next blank space. Meaning deleting only one word at the left of the cursor.

Answer (score 2):

For the use case of deleting a line, regardless of key repetition:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to go to the start of the line  and use

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to delete the line when at position 0

and  use

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to go to the end of line

It is actually faster to navigate, though It will not reduce key repetition time.

Comment: +1 and Thanks for the help. But I actually wanted to reduce the repetition time.